# For-loop with RxJava2 or RxKotlin

Tags: android, for-loop, android-asynctask, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I want to build a async operation that iterates chars in given string. I have a char array taken by `"mystring".toCharArray()`. I want to iterate each 10th character by using RX.

I know i can do it with [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and for-loops but i thought RX would be more elegant solution. I have read [documentations](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) but did not recognize how to do it.

Another idea in my mind to create a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) and fire `onNext()` in  a for-loop that index increments by 10 with subscription.

PS: `"mystring"` can be much more larger like a json, xml or etc. Please feel free to comment about ram profiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxJava doesn't support primitive arrays, but you can use a for loop in the form of the `range` operator and index into a primitive array. With some index arithmetic, you can get every 10th character easily:

```
char[] chars = ...

Observable.range(0, chars.length)
    .filter(idx -> idx % 10 == 0)
    .map(idx -> chars[idx])
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I got it, Something is niggling my mind. With PublishSubject i can iterate less which makes it faster?

Comment: Depends on what you have written and how do you measure it as "faster".

Comment: Doing for-loops in Java and not in RxJava has always lower overhead. I use a scrabble benchmark to measure stream processing libraries and you can get as 4x more overhead with RxJava compared to a plain for loop when everything is synchronous.

Comment: You are right. I also wants to write a code that easy to read. Its a trade-off. I will stick with range. Thanks